How do I apply Post Processing to UI but not to the rest of the scene?
Goal: Get functional/interactable UI with separate post processing than other objects in scene
I’ve tried the following:

Camera Stacking

makes the camera at the bottom of the stack also affected by post processing
for more info:

Main Camera only renders the default layer with a Default layer PPV
UI Camera only renderers the UI layer with a UI layer PPV
Main Camera is the Base camera with the UI camera as the Overlay


see image: 


Custom Render Feature

creates the image above, but the UI is no longer interactable
for more info:

Made a new Custom Renderer for the UI camera
UI camera outputs renderer data to a Render Texture
Using a Fullscreen Render Feature, blit the output of the UI camera Render Texture to the Main Camera (looks great! but UI isn’t interactable…)


see image:



The second image is the target result, but the UI needs to be interactable :/
A tiny bit more info: the PPV for UI adds Bloom; PPV for 3D scene just adds Contrast, the boxes in the top left are UnityUI buttons

Assuming that you are using different culling masks for the Base and the UI Camera, Check Event Camera Property of your canvas. That might be set to your base camera. Most likely that won't work as the base camera is not rendering the UI anymore.

My canvas's worldCamera is set to my 3D Camera. Unfortunately changing this property doesn't work.
